# Error while making symbolic links for nvim

Tags: unix, zsh

So I was making a symbolic links for nvim so that if i use vim command it opens nvim.

So I used this code

```
ln -s (which nvim) /usr/local/bin/vim
```

but when i ran the command it showed this error

```
zsh: unknown file attribute: h
```

so plz tell me my mistake and solution for that

Comment: `(which nvim)` should have been `$(which nvim)`.

Comment: Or `\`which nvim\`` (backtick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the path to nvim as the first parameter, i.e.

```
ln -s =nvim /usr/local/bin/vim
```

In general, `=foo` expands to the absolute path of the command foo (by using PATH search).

Answer (score 1):

You might have both `vim` and `nvim` symlink in homebrew. If so, remove the symlink of `vim` and then re-create it.

`brew unlink vim` --> it should be showing this message if successfully `Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/vim/9.0.1400... 187 symlinks removed.`

Then, add the symlink to `vim` again:
`ln -s $(which nvim) /opt/homebrew/bin/vim`